# How to fix body-parser not parsing html form date input field in express NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to get date from html form with input field of type "datetime-local". I'm using body-parser for parsing forms. But as I console.log req.body.mydate, it returns undefined. I want to extract the input date and store in mongodb.

Here is my html code.

```
<form action="/greet" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="expiry_date">Expiry Date</label>
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3' name='expiry_date'>
                            <input type='datetime-local' class='date' data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" action='/greet'>Create</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-right">
            </div>
        </form>
```

And here's my route handling post request for that url.

```
router.post('/greet', (req, res)=>{
    var expireAt = req.body.expiry_date;
    console.log(expireAt)
    res.send(expireAt)
})
```

I expect to get date inputted but all I get is undefined when I console.log the var expireAt.

Comment: The `name` attribute goes on your `<input>`, not a `<div>` containing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using name="expiry_date" in  and not in  tag. Correcting that fixed it.